# Package version between two computers is different

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, laptop

I've just installed Ubuntu onto my laptop so I could program on the go, and I'm having an issue where a specific package is an older version on my laptop vs my desktop.

The package is `liballegro5-dev`

Both systems tell me they are up to date when I run `sudo apt update`

On my desktop Allegro5 is version 5.2.7, whereas on my laptop it is 5.2.6.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you *certain* you're running the same version of Ubuntu on both systems? Based [on the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~allegro/+archive/ubuntu/5.2), 5.2.6 shows as being available only for 20.10 and 21.04, whereas 5.2.7 is available for 20.04 and 21.10 

Comment: Just checked, both are running 20.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I guess I had added the allegro repository on my first machine, and then completely forgot about!

If anyone else has this issue. You need to add the allegro ppa to get the latest updates:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:allegro/5.2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The above commands will add the repostory, give you the latest updates, then upgrade your packages.